# OutOf MemoryException windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have created a dynamic pivot in which the data is binded through a list in which the data changes randomly almost the range is between 100 - 150 entries in the list . All goes well the data get added to the list but when the data is binded the app terminates unexpectedly and show the out of memory exception

My code is somehow like this xaml

```
<Controls:Pivot x:Name="pvtDeals" Background="Gray" ItemsSource="{Binding CityItemList}" Grid.Row="1">
   <Controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid >
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Image x:Name="imgDeal" Tag="0" Source="{Binding ImageLink}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
               <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
               <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
                   <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="2"/>
               </ScrollViewer>
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Controls:Pivot>
```

cs code

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result); // from XML string, e.g.


// SaveDealInfoToIsolatedStorage(e.Result);

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]*>");

        var Channel = xml.Root.Elements("channel").ToList();
        var items = Channel[0].Elements("item").ToList();
        App.MainViewModel.CityItemList.Clear();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            App.MainViewModel.CityItemList.Add(new Model.CityItems
                {
                    Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                    Description = rx.Replace(item.Element("description").Value.Replace("\"", string.Empty), string.Empty),
                    ImageLink = item.Element("imageURL").Value,//image,
                    WebLink = item.Element("link").Value
                });

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(App.MainViewModel.CityItemList.Count.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: What is the question? What causes this, how to avoid it, or how to handle it when it happens?

Comment: Code you've posted doesn't leak any memory is what I think, I suspect leak would be somewhere else

Comment: @Theodoros Yes My question is What causes this then how to avoid and handle it.  The code runs well for about 70 entries in the device but same fails in the emulator.   Entries above 70 is failing in both.